# Count Number of Consecutive Occurrence of values in Google sheets

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, vlookup, countif, google-query-language

[image]

This is the original data, all the data are of two kinds: red and black. And then, I want to study the occurrence of all the blocks. The result will be like this:

[image]

It means the first streak of red(from index 1 to 3) has a length of 3, and the second streak which is black(from index 4 to 5) has a length of 2...

I want to find out an elegant way to calculate it but in sheets, it's very hard. `COUNTIF` and `ROWS` all can't perfectly resolve this problem.

Do you have an elegant way?

Comment: Do NOT share [spreadsheets](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455)/[images](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) as the only source of data. Make sure to add input and expected output as **plain text table** to the question. [Click here](//webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855) to create a table easily. Adding such tables makes **it is easier to copy/paste**. Your question may be closed, if it isn't self contained. Your table should be a minimal example.[Your email address can also be accessed by the public](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/394304), if you share Google files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(REGEXREPLACE(QUERY({TEXT(
 VLOOKUP(ROW(B2:B20), QUERY((B2:B20<>B1:B19)*ROW(B2:B20), 
 "where Col1 <>0"), 1, 1), "000000")&"×"&B2:B20}, 
 "select Col1,count(Col1) group by Col1 label count(Col1)''")&"", "(.+×)", ), 
 "where Col1 is not null"))
```

[image]

Comment: thank you very much, I have never heard of query language in sheets before. It's amazing, I learned SQL 10 years ago, now I can use it in sheets.

Comment: I'm trying to use this formula but I get an #ERROR. I can't really tell what is wrong. I tried just subsituting the cell-ranges with my own but it just gives an #ERROR no matter what I put in. Any idea what might be wrong?
Picture: https://imgur.com/a/FUNUatX

Comment: @mTv can you share a copy of your sheet?

Comment: Sure, https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1OMxOGU1fMjjZ-RqpdeUopV0RCsWvNuDSY8Pgc3-iEtI/edit?usp=sharing. Trying to make a formula to calculate streaks into a format like the one you posted based on the name in the "Owner" column. First 10 turns are invalid

Comment: @mTv try in your sheet: `=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(REGEXREPLACE(QUERY({TEXT(
 VLOOKUP(ROW(B2:B1000); QUERY((B2:B1000<>B1:B999)*ROW(B2:B1000); 
 "where Col1 <>0"); 1; 1); "000000")&"×"&B2:B1000}; 
 "select Col1,count(Col1) group by Col1 label count(Col1)''")&""; "(.+×)"; ); 
 "where Col1 is not null"; ))`

Comment: Great thank you! What did you change?

Comment: @mTv pretty much nothing, just adapted it to your non-english locale

Comment: Seems like the only thing you did was replace ',' with ';'. I didn't know that mattered. Well thanks a lot!

Comment: @mTv see: https://stackoverflow.com/q/73767719/5632629

Answer (score 1):

Not sure it's elegant, but you could add two helper columns, the first column checks if the record has changed, and the second counts until the next change using a MATCH.  Note you'd need an extra "TRUE" below the last record to catch the last streak.  Then you can use FILTER to show the blocks and occurances.
[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, even though it has so many steps to achieve, I applied this method to my work and finished it.